# How can I get a user via UserID in a slash command?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have been programming a discord bot, following tutorials as needed since I am quite new, but I have come across a problem that, as simple as it sounds, I can't seem to solve.
I am trying to draw a leaderboard, and for each placement on the leaderboard I want to get the user's avatar to draw onto the leaderboard. To do this, I want to be able to get the user through just the UserId. However, I am doing all of this in a separate slash command. Here is a **very** simplified version of what I'm trying to do to give some context and/or maybe a better explanation:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, AttachmentBuilder } = require('discord.js');
// ... some functions and what not go here
module.exports = {
   //... lines for setting up the command go here

   async execute(interaction){
       const data = fetchData();  //A function that gets the whole list of data; did not put it in the codeblock to save on space since it's not necessary
       // ... a bunch of stuff, ordering my data, etc.
       data.forEach(async (userData, index) => {
          // And here begins my issue. The line below is just what I have attempted to do
          const target = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(userData.UserId); 
       });
   };
}
```

I have done a fair bit of research, and the only feasible solution I could find (which you can see is in the above example code) is to do
`const target = interaction.guild.members.cache.get("User_ID");`
However, even though I can log the return in the console, if I tried to do something like "target.user" it would say target is undefined. And, in case it helps, yes, I do have GuildMembers in my intents.

Comment: What is `fetchData`?

Comment: @kennarddh That just gives me the whole list of data I had saved in a file; I did not show the whole function to save on space since it doesn't really concern my problem. Sorry, I did not make that clear; I've edited my question.

Comment: Are you trying to get member by user id?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get the member by UserId.

Comment: Can you try this `await interaction.guild.members.fetch('userid')`? You need to use forof loop because `forEach` cannot be async.

Comment: I tried it out and it works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `members.fetch` since it's async you need to change your `forEach` to `forof` because `forEach` is synchronous

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder, AttachmentBuilder } = require('discord.js');
// ... some functions and what not go here
module.exports = {
   //... lines for setting up the command go here

   async execute(interaction) {
       const data = fetchData();  //A function that gets the whole list of data; did not put it in the codeblock to save on space since it's not necessary
       // ... a bunch of stuff, ordering my data, etc.
       for (const userData of data) {
         const target = await interaction.guild.members.fetch(userData.UserId)
       }
   };
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to get the id of the user that ran the slash command, you can use `interaction.user.id`.

To get a user by id, you can run:

```js
//Inside the execute function of the slash command

interaction.guild.members.cache.get("user_id").then(function(user){
    //Do something with user
}
```

Comment: the problem still persists; I continue to get the error: "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')." Even though the  interaction.guild.members.cache.get("user_id") does return me something, whenever I try to do something with it I just get an error saying it is undefined.

Comment: This might be because the user is not in the cache. Maybe try using .fetch rather than cache.get. Also make sure that your request the GuildMembers intent in bot the dev portal and in your code.